# AWS Serverless Template in Visual Studio 2019 Removes the IIS Express Debug Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

When I use the AWS SDK to create a serverless application in visual studio 2019 I have only the Mock Lambda Test Tool as a debug tool. The option to select IIS Express is not longer available in the console tool bar.

Comment: Yes. That option is not there anymore. It's annoying to copy and paste the API gateway payload everything to debug the Web API (Serverless Lambda) in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a bug in VS tool. It has been tagged as a bug. https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/issues/86